# is my menu-block not properly inserted?

Tags: routes, blocks

quite new to drupal and having a small issue i can't seem to solve.
it's quite a lot to start to explain so i think it's best to just send you the link and explain the problem.

take a look at www.contribute.be
i have inserted a new menu block called 'News' + a menu link to that block.
Now i have 2 issues with this:

1) when i click on a job (in the section underneath), the job description should slide out in the same place (what it does when the News block is not enabled) but what happens is it jumps to the news block first
2) similar problem: when i click on a customer case (in the second section of customers), it should link to another content type with the customer case in full, but what happens is the menublock 'News' is displayed as well.

It seems to be getting in the way of the other blocks and content types.
I have looked but cannot find the solution.

Can somebody assist?

Thx
B

Comment: before anyone takes the time to read this, i found the solution. It was a setting in drupal to show the block only on listed pages. But now it doesn't show on the homepage anymore either. I'm looking further. Any help of course is appreciated. Sorry for your time

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the News block is NOT on the main page (#block-block-9 is not in source code). When clicking a job title, the visitor is taken to /jobs and there IS a News block. Since it's just before the Jobs block and the page seems to remember the scroll offset, the visitor sees the news block instead of the jobs block (which is then right below).

Comment: correct, it was on the main page but i selected the option to show the block only on listed pages so it wouldn't show up on the other (separate) articles. The only thing is that it disappeared from the main page too now and i don't know how to select the main page as a listed page

Comment: but i seem to have fixed it now. In the configuration mode of the block, I selected only the listed pages and added  <front> in the description box underneath. I think this is a newbie thing, but i'm learning